# jQuery animation sequence

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein, jquery-animate

I'm working on a website where I want to make a nice menu, that fades in link by link.

Se code below:
First fade in #navigation a.toplevel, then the first #navigation dt, and then the next, and the next until there ain't no more.

How do you make a sequence of fadein?

```
<div id="navigation">
        <a href="#" class="toplevel">Solutions</a>
        <dl> 
            <dt><a href="#">ERP</a></dt>             
            <dd> 
              <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>                     
                    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>                     
                    <li><a href="#">Something else</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </dd>  
            <dt><a href="#">CRM</a></dt>             
            <dd> 
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>                     
                    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>                     
                    <li><a href="#">Something else</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </dd> 
            <dt><a href="#">BI</a></dt>             
            <dd> 
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>                     
                    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>                     
                    <li><a href="#">Something else</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </dd> 
        </dl> 
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you mean like this?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8gFLg/2/

```
$('#navigation > a, #navigation dt').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).delay( idx * 600 ).fadeIn( 600 );
});
```

Comment: Exactly! Can you tell me then, how to add a slideDown on another element after the last DT has faded in?

And maybe how to add a class, that fades in afterwards?

Comment: @Kenneth B: I would need more detail for the slideDown. Like which element is sliding down? Did you mean each `<dd>`? Also, not sure what you mean by adding a class that fades in.

Comment: @Kenneth B: Maybe this is what you meant for the slideDown? http://jsfiddle.net/8gFLg/3/

Answer (score 0):

Simply nest another fadein inside your fadein function.

```
 $('#navigation a.toplevel').fadeIn(function(){
      $('#nextthing').fadeIn(function(){
          $('#thenextthing').fadeIn();
      });
 });
```

---

Do you need to know how to loop through the dt's?

Comment: Thank you! :-) If I do this, let's say 10 times, to make sure that even though my client adds some links, the effect will still work, then IE will complain because there aren't 10 yet. How do I get by this? An IF?

Comment: How can I get the different DT's to fadeIn after eachother, and not the same time, without giving them different classes?

Comment: The code above should do one after another , not at the same time...
I will make a comment later with a way of counting and looping through each dt

Answer (score 0):

Oops.. just realized that the spelled-out and somewhat laborious solution suggested below is the equivalent of the much shorter and smarter one suggested by user113716 above - on condition however, that the items to animate are conveniently arranged in the correct sequence in html.

If that's not the case, you can still use this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var time=0;
     var interval=500;
     $('#id1').delay(time).animate({top:100},interval);
     time=time+interval;
     $('#id2').delay(time).animate({top:100},interval);
     time=time+interval;
     interval=1000;
     $('#id3').delay(time).animate({top:100},interval);
     time=time+interval;
     $('#id4').delay(time).animate({top:100},interval);
     time=time+interval;
 })
```

Here is a javascript fiddle based on this code: http://jsfiddle.net/dj89d/